# AppDomain PrivateBinPath 3 level in path

Tags: c#, appdomain, assemblyresolve

I configure my PrivateBinPath as follows:

plugins;plugins\pluginA;plugins\pluginA\resources;...

I can see in the fusion log the application ignores all paths like plugins\pluginA\resources. The directories exist, but every path with more than two level is ignored.

Is there a limitation of the relative paths in PrivateBinPath?

Comment: You sure the folder is named `ressources` and not `resources`?

Comment: You are right it is resources, my mistake, but that was just an example. There are other folders like plugins\pluginD\input and these folders are also ignored.